# How to retrieve organic post's insights in day granularity on facebook API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I reviewed the documentation and I have seen that many metrics are possible in lifetime granularity and not daily.
`https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v17.0/insights#page-post-impressions`

There is any way to get the data in day granularity?

for instance - get the impressions and clicks of the post.

Comment: You can get the granularities mentioned there, that's it.